# symfony: how to pass to uploaded bundle its own path

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

I am using symfony 3.3

I have created a bundle which I install via composer into `vendor/` in my application. I have this bundle to require some yml files which I inject to it via dependency injection. So far everything is ok. But I also have  one yml file already inside this bundle and this bundle has to know this (his own) file's path.

Currently I have this in one of my bundle's classes

```
protected const LOCAL_FILE = __DIR__.'/../Resources/translations/ru.yml';
```

It works just fine but I do not think it is a proper solution. I try to pass to this class a `%kernel.root_dir%` but from that I still can't guess the whole path.

How ought I to do it the best way?

UPDATE: having made what zerkms suggested I get the result invoking this method the following way:

```
  my.translator:
      ...
      calls:
          - method: configure
            arguments:
               ...
               - '@kernel'
```

and the part with `locateResource`

```
 protected const LOCAL_FILE = '@MyBundle/Resources/translations/ru.yml';
  ....
  ....
  $this->kernel->locateResource(self::LOCAL_FILE)
```

Comment: Check kernel's `locateResource` method. http://api.symfony.com/3.3/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/KernelInterface.html#method_locateResource

Comment: @zerkms what do I pass to my class' constructor in `services.yml` to be able to access this method?

Comment: `@kernel`? ........

Comment: It works! thats! can you make an answer with this suggestion so that I might accept it?

Comment: I have. Could you please also show how exactly you invoked that method so that the answer reflected your very case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have used the [`Symfony\Component\HttpKernel::locateResource()`](http://api.symfony.com/3.3/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/KernelInterface.html#method_locateResource) method.

And the kernel object is available through the `@kernel` id in the container.

Comment: it worked. I updated my post to show how I made it work

Comment: @user7808407 yep, but what did you pass to `locateResource`.